# Let $S$ be the area of the region enclosed by $y=e^{-x^2},y=0,x=0$ and $x=1$.Then

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $S$ be the area of the region enclosed by $y=e^{-x^2},y=0,x=0$ and $x=1$.Then
$(A)S\geq\frac{1}{e}$
$(B)S\geq1-\frac{1}{e}$
$(C)S\leq\frac{1}{4}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}})$
$(D)S\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt e}(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$

---

$S=\int_0^1e^{-x^2}dx$ 
Put $x^2=t$
$S=\int_0^1\frac{e^{-t}}{2\sqrt t}dt$
I found out that the function $\frac{e^{-x}}{2\sqrt x}$ is a decreasing function in the domain $x>0$ but i cannot deduce the answer.
The correct answers are given to be $(A),(B),(D)$.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to integrate. In fact you cannot integrate this expression you have to do some more clever things.

Hint 1:
$$e^{-x^2} \ge \frac{1}{e} \text{ when } 0 \le x \le 1$$

Hint 2:
$$e^{-x^2} \ge 1 - x^2$$

Hint 3:

$$f(x) > g(x) \implies \int f(x) dx > \int g(x) dx$$

Hint 4:
$$a > b \text{ and } b > c \implies a > c$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrand is known exactly $\frac{\sqrt \pi }{2}erf(1).$

Comment: No Narasimham How can we calculate $\error f(1)$

Comment: $ erf(1) \approx 0.84270079 $

Comment: Would you like to explain me how can we get it, Thanks.

Comment: clearly not the point of this exercise

Comment: @juantheron   It is so standard in statistics, probability, found in several places https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function. Gaussian curve has DE $dy/dx = - x\, y/  \sigma^2$, maybe useful in such computations.